# titanium appcelerator: Delete Selected Rows

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I want to delete the selected data on button click which data has

```
hasCheck=true
```

in the titanium appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

file.xml (view):

```
<ListView id="list" onItemclick="onListViewItemclick" >
    <Templates>
    </Templates>
    <ListSection id="section"/>
</ListView>
```

file.js (controller):

```
function onListViewItemclick(e) {
    var item = $.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);

    if (item.hasCheck) {
        $.section.deleteItemsAt(e.itemIndex, $.section.items.length);
    }
}
```